# Trying to Plot FFT for an Image Array

Tags: python, image, fft

I'm trying to create a signal plot for an array of pictures using the following code:

```
import numpy as np
import sys
import matplotlib.image as mpimg
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

imgArr = {}
stnArr = {}
frmArr = {}
sgnArr = {}

for i in range(1,2397):
    imgArr[i] = mpimg.imread("20210209_themis_rank"+ str(i)+ ".png")
    stnArr[i] = np.mean([imgArr[i]]/std(imgArr[i]))
    frmArr[i] = i

signal = np.fft.fft(imgArr[i])

for i in range(1,2397):
    plt.plot(frmArr,np.abs(signal))

plt.show()
```

However, I keep on running into the following error. How can I get it to work?

```
raise ValueError(f"x and y must have same first dimension, but "
ValueError: x and y must have same first dimension, but have shapes (1,) and (600, 600, 4)
```

Comment: have you got this working using just a single image ?

Comment: @ScottStensland yes, still not working.